# How to deploy an MVC 4 application to a Windows Web Server based dedicated hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to deploy an MVC 4 web application to a Windows Web Server 2008 based dedicated hosting. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express as my back-end database. What steps will I need to take regarding the following:

1. Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on the web server and deploying my database.
2. Managing SQL Express database remotely using SSMS.
3. Configuring database path in my EF5 generated model
4. Deploying my application
5. Managing changes to my application.

Can someone provide me a detailed answer/some good links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on the web server and deploying my database.

This depends on your provider. Most providers, if not all, allow you to install your own **licensed** SQL Server. If you will be using an Express edition then it is, and should be, 100% allowable by your provider. The only step you need here is to [go to download page of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438) and download the appropriate file you need. The files you need on that page are the ones with **"ADV"** in its name. Choose **x64** if you will install a 64-bit OS or choose **x86** if you will install a 32-bit OS.

> Managing SQL Express database remotely using SSMS.

This depends on the firewall set by your provider. But basically this is how you will allow remote access to your SQL Server:

**For Windows 2008 R2**

1. Login to your dedicated server using Remote Desktop. If you don't know how to do this, it's best that you consult with your provider.
2. Go to Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools -> `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
3. On the window that open in step #2, expand SQL Server Configuration Manager (Local) -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLExpress
4. On the right pane, right-click TCP/IP and select Properties.
5. Select the IP Addresses tab and then scroll to the **IP All** section.
6. Set/change the TCP Port value to/from 1433 to 14333 (or any other port) and then click OK.
7. Right-click TCP/IP again and `Enable` it
8. Restart your SQL Server by going to Start -> All Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> Restart. The `Restart` is on the left pane.

> Configuring database path in my EF5 generated model

Unfortunately, I cannot answer this one as I believe you are using the EF designer in creating your model.  I never worked with EF that way, but only by code-first. I have to skip this part and let you Google this.

> Deploying my application

There is already [a good documentation written here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7) so I will not dupliate it here. Basically what you need to do is enable FTP on your dedicated server. Then once that is setup you can go on with **bin-deploying** your application.

> Managing changes to my application.

I assume what you are asking here is that if you have changes to your application, how would you re-deploy it. A **bin-deployment** will not hurt. Deploying only the files in which you have changes is a good approach. Knowing which files changed can vary depending on the tools you use. In addition, if you don't have any fancy setup that will tell your users you are deploying changes to your site, you might want to [take a look at this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx). It tells you to put a `App_Offline.htm` file in your root web directory. That should still work with MVC, after all MVC is still ASP.Net.