# Web Server to Host my MVC4 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, hosting

> Hi i'm trying to host an mvc4 web application on a web server and it is not working. Do i need to install something in particular so that it works? And what type of web server is the best for this type of situation?

Comment: See the following Question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008058/how-to-deploy-an-mvc-4-application-to-a-windows-web-server-based-dedicated-hosti

Answer (score 1):

You will need:

- IIS, preferably IIS 7+
- .Net installed on the server
- make sure the framework is set correctly

Take a look [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1198076.aspx/)

if you have all this set up, let us know the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

1)IIS 7.5

2) MVC4 and Framework 4.5 should be installed

3) Also check that in ApplicationPools you set framawork 4.0 for your site (default is 2.0)

It would be better if you show a certain error you receive.

Comment: @christiandev Sorry, I've not fully read your answer. We think in a same way, so I vote up for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

See the following Question... [How to deploy an MVC 4 application to a Windows Web Server based dedicated hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008058/how-to-deploy-an-mvc-4-application-to-a-windows-web-server-based-dedicated-hosti)

It seems incredabily relevant to what you are asking.

Also for future reference read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before asking questions